# Pyspark command not recognized (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed python and spark but when i run pyspark command on anaconda, it gives me an error

```
(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>pyspark
usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir] [--paths] [--json] [subcommand]
jupyter: error: one of the arguments --version subcommand --config-dir --data-dir --runtime-dir --paths is required
```

when i execute `spark-shell`, it is working fine

Comment: seems your pyspark executable is pointing towards jupyter... there is something wrong when you were setting it up. try to reinstall pyspark and see if it helps

Comment: i have uninstalled it and again installed it but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the installation, python 3.8 was not supporting pyspark 3+, so i have installed the previous version of python

Comment: Please edit your existing answer and update it.